# How to deal with flag variables in embedded system

Tags: variables, embedded, flags

I am doing a project on embedded system where I am changing a flag variable 'x_flag' upon interrupt. This flag variable is *global* and accessed in other source files to check the state of condition of events too.

I know the troubles dealing with global variables, but I would like to ask you about how can I access the current state of 'x_flag' in other source files?

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to expose variables is to make a GetXFlagState() function in the class which owns it. That way the owner class remains in control.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. Everything else is obfuscation. Other source files need not access that flag directly. Of course you will have to declare the flag as `static volatile` at file scope, in the file where the ISR resides. But there is never a reason to make it global.

Answer (score 4):

In your c-file you can define it like

```
volatile int x_flag;

void myISRFunction(void)
{
    x_flag = 1;
}
```

And in your header file you add a declaration

```
extern volatile int x_flag;
```

Then you only need to include the header file from the other c-file to be able to access `x_flag`

But there you should also disable the interrupt when accessing/modifing the flag.

```
#include "myISR.h"

void someFunc()
{
  int local_x_flag;

  disableInterrupts();
  local_x_flag = x_flag;
  x_flag = 0;
  enableInterrupts();

  if ( local_x_flag )
    doSomething();
}
```

Note that if the flag is really a hardware register, you may need to be more careful, as disabling interrupts will not stop the hardware from altering the value of the flag and clearing it explicitly may or may not be allowed.  In that case, you'll need to look carefully at the hardware documentation to find out what is and is not safe (and/or talk to whoever is designing it, if you're working with hardware engineers).

Comment: Ideally also the data type used for `x_flag` should be atomic on the target architecture.  That may not be the case for `int` on an 8-bit system for example.  However if it is only ever used for values 0 and 1, this may not matter, but it is not clear whether `x_flag` is intended to be a single flag or a set of flag *bits*.

Comment: @Clifford I can't see a good reason why it should be atomic, even with a byte you can't modify a single bit in an atomic way on many platforms. And I don't like to depend on specific CPU features and the compiler output. So I prefere to build an atomic block with disable/enable interrupts

Comment: As I said, in this case it does not matter.  For shared memory in general it is a consideration.  For my point about bit flags, you have a point simply being atomic is not helpful in a read-write-modify situation.

Comment: A better way is to make `x_flag` static volatile. Put the "critical section" code inside the getter function that returns a copy of the variable. Do not use `extern`/globals. There is never a reason to do so.

Comment: @Lundin The OP asked primary how to access a variable from another module. But you are right, globals are always a bad idea and here are many better solutions possible